# Is it a good practice to write method' logic in my Junit test case?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, dependency-injection, dependencies

I am new to Junit and was wondering if we could do so.
The reason behind asking this question is that sometimes the method we are testing can have underlying logic which might be dependent on several other methods present in some different class (especially in case of Hibernte) and in such cases, to evaluate the expected value of our test, we left with no option but writing all those dependencies in my test class itself so that on run time, it could automatically get us the expected value of test.
thanks.

Comment: You should have as little logic as possible in your test.

Comment: You should organize your code so that you'd be able to mock all of the dependencies.